# Ecto.Schema differences between nilify_all, nothing, and delete_all?

Tags: elixir, schema, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am defining a schema for my `user` and `role` models in Phoenix app. Role `has_many` users and user `belongs_to` a role. It seems like there are 3 different `on_delete:` options: `nilify_all`, `nothing`(default), and `delete_all`.

When I look at [Ecto.Schema](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html) page, I don't really find definition of what each does.

What is the difference between `nilify_all`, `nothing`, and `delete_all` - when should I use each?

Comment: Just wanted to say that the docs don't recommend using this option. Instead, they recommend setting it on the DB (migration) directly. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3

Answer (score 12):

The `on_delete` option specifies what should happen to the associated records when a record is deleted.

Considering your example where a `role` has many `users`:

- `delete_all`: Deletes the associated records when the parent record is deleted. For example in your case deleting a `role` will delete all the `users` that are associated with that role.
- `nilify_all`: This sets the key in the associated table that points to the parent record to `nil` when the parent record is deleted. For example when a role is deleted, this will set the `role_id` in the `users` table to `nil` of those users that belonged to that role.
- `nothing`: This would not do anything to the associated records when the parent record is deleted. This will however throw an error if the associated table has a foreign key constraint back to the parent table.

Comment: is there a way to :protect the role from deleted? let's say accidentally deleted role

Comment: @Loonb In this case you would use the `:restrict` option. This will stop a `role` being deleted if it's in use by users, however it won't stop a role that is unused from being deleted.